# ViewModel null on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm

Hi I have been looking for a solution to this problem but I had no luck. Using my viewmodel POST can not get the data, no matter how you do always the object is null. I'll put the code so you can see to which I refer.

This is my ViewModel

```
public class ProyectosCompletos
{
   public IEnumerable<Proyecto> Proyectos { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Informacion> Informaciones { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Diseno> Disenos { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Procedimiento> Procedimientos { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Programacion> Programaciones { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Instalacion> Instalaciones { get; set; }
}
```

This is the model project, it would be the "main" model

```
public class Proyecto
{
    public int ProyectoID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Elaboracion> Elaboraciones { get; set; }
    public virtual Procedimiento Procedimiento { get; set; }
    public virtual Informacion Informacion { get; set; }
    public virtual Instalacion Instalacion { get; set; }
    public virtual Diseno Diseno { get; set; }
    public virtual Programacion Programacion { get; set; }
}
```

This is for example the Instalacion model, and the others are similar

```
public class Instalacion
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Proyecto")]
    public int ProyectoID { get; set; }

    public double HardwareNota { get; set; }
    public double SoftwareNota { get; set; }

    public virtual Proyecto Proyecto { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InstalacionEntrada> Entradas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InstalacionAnotacion> Anotaciones { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Controller

```
public ActionResult Docente(int? ListaProyectos)
{
   //This code is not relevant to the problem
   var viewModel = new ProyectosCompletos();
   string usuarioActualId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
   ApplicationUser usuarioActual = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == usuarioActualId);
   var pro = db.Elaboraciones
              .Where(e => e.ApplicationUserID == usuarioActual.Id)
              .Select(e => new { e.ProyectoID, e.Proyecto.Titulo});
   ViewBag.ListaProyectos = new SelectList(pro, "ProyectoID", "Titulo");

    //THIS IS WHAT MATTERS
    if (ListaProyectos != null)
    {
       ViewBag.ProyectoID = ListaProyectos.Value;

       viewModel.Proyectos = db.Proyectos.Where(p => p.Archivar == false && p.ProyectoID == ListaProyectos.Value);
       viewModel.Informaciones = db.Informaciones.Where(i => i.ProyectoID == ListaProyectos.Value);
       viewModel.Procedimientos = db.Procedimientos.Where(i => i.ProyectoID == ListaProyectos.Value);
       viewModel.Disenos = db.Disenos.Where(i => i.ProyectoID == ListaProyectos.Value);
       viewModel.Programaciones = db.Programaciones.Where(i => i.ProyectoID == ListaProyectos.Value);
       viewModel.Instalaciones = db.Instalaciones.Where(i => i.ProyectoID == ListaProyectos.Value);
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

For GET no problem to get the data. I get them properly and see the view

```
public ActionResult Docente(int ListaProyectos, ProyectosCompletos viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       db.Entry(viewModel.Informaciones).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.Entry(viewModel.Disenos).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.Entry(viewModel.Procedimientos).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.Entry(viewModel.Programaciones).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.Entry(viewModel.Instalaciones).State = EntityState.Modified;

       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Docente");
    }
 }
```

But to return to the POST form the object is completely empty.
Finally I put the view, I will reduce it a bit because it is already long enough question

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   foreach (var item in Model.Proyectos)
   {
      <h3>@item.Titulo</h3>
      @if (Model.Instalaciones != null)
      {
        foreach (var instalacion in Model.Instalaciones)
        {
           Nota: @Html.EditorFor(m => instalacion.HardwareNota, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => instalacion.HardwareNota, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

           Nota: @Html.EditorFor(m => instalacion.SoftwareNota, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => instalacion.SoftwareNota, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        }
    }
 }
 <input type="submit" value="Guardar Cambios" class="btn btn-success" /> 
}
```

I hope you can help me out, thanks !!

Comment: most likely the default-binder has some issues with your `IEnumerable<...>`s and it should work if you replace those with `List<..>` or simply arrays

Comment: shouldn't you also add a parameter (ListaProyectos) to -- >return RedirectToAction("Docente");

Comment: @CarstenKönig I replaced the IEnumerable<..> with a List<..> then i have to put .ToList() in each viewModel. But the result is the same a null object